# Salt with jumpbox

Tags: ssh, salt-stack

I will try to describe the issue in points:

- I use salt-sproxy + pillar on my local machine
- I can use it to manage network gears I have access directly to from my local ubuntu machine
- I have some gears which are accessible only via a jumpbox
- so to access them:
  My machine ssh ---> jumpbox ssh ---> router
- by adding jump box info in ~/.ssh/config, I can access my router directly, ie jumpbox is transparent to me
- By using salt, I am not able to access these gears.

So it seems that salt isn't checking ~/.ssh/config to know how to access my router.

Is there any variable to define in salt master file to make it works? or in a pillar file?

BR
Mou

Answer (score 0):

*salt-ssh* should read your `~/.ssh/config` (via openssh) but clearly *salt-sproxy* doesn't.

However you should be able to specify ProxyJump as an ssh option as stated in the [documentation about ssh roster](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/ssh/roster.html) since [salt-sproxy also reads rosters](https://github.com/mirceaulinic/salt-sproxy#is-salt-sproxy-a-wrapper-around-salt-ssh).